# use Apache Camel for file transfer style integration?

Tags: apache-camel, integration

my question is for file transfer style enterprise integration, is it really worth using EIP framework such as Apache Camel? Thanks for any advice.

The requirements: large size csv-like structure text files; there is some converting happening before they are stored into database. Performance could be a concern here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Apache Camel, if

- you already know the framework and it is a no brainer for you to implement the route
- you don't know the framework but like to learn it
- it is foreseeable that the route will be expanded (other transformations and/or access to external services such as web services, e-mail, etc.)
- you need a structured way to define the transformation route
- you need build-in monitoring possibilities
- ...

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Camel for couple of years and the main use case have always been file transfer.
In my opinion file transfer is not as simple as it looks like and a framework like Camel will be very beneficial. Different file systems has different restrictions and Camel file endpoints have different strategies for dealing with concurrent file access, transaction behavior, retry longing, error handling, streaming, monitoring, statistics, scaling, etc.

On the other hand, if you are very sure that you will not need any of the above and your file transfer will be very very simple (any file transfer looks so at the beginning) then it might be easier to write your own file transfer logic, but I'm sure if you use Camel, it will be shorter, easier to understand and maintain and extend for future requirements.

My 2p

Answer (score 0):

Can you more elaborate on your question or requirement? If it is solely for file transfer style I think it is worth to use it as it has variety file transfer style function and features.maybe u can try refer post below
[Apache Camel and other ESB products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792519/apache-camel-and-other-esb-products)