# Can I use Apache Camel as ESB?

Tags: apache-camel, esb, enterprise-integration

I was trying to know more about [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/), Mule ESB, JBoss ESB]...and in general speaking about [ESB](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus). I can find several ESB characteristic in Apache Camel. So, can I use Apache Camel like ESB or is Apache ServiceMix is the best fit?

Comment: Actually Camel is ESB by nature. So what is a question? Also when you read about different ESBs keep an eye on date of materials. All changes pretty fast. Some products and documents are out-of-date...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Apache Camel has to be seen as a part of an ESB as it is strong in the area of routing and mediation (transforming message formats, talking to different protocols).

In order to have a meaningful ESB setup, you also want to have a message broker, e.g. [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org) and a framework which is supporting you in service orchestration (versioning, deployment, ...), e.g. [Apache Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org).

All these technologies (plus some additional projects) are actually bundled in the [Apache Servicemix](https://servicemix.apache.org) distribution, so if you are looking for an Open Source solution, this might be a good start for you. As far as I know, at least Camel, ActiveMQ and Karaf are core components of enterprise products like JBoss Fuse.

Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792519/apache-camel-and-other-esb-products?rq=1) for a more comprehensive discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jboss Fuse which is nothing but a karaf(OSGI Container) with Apache Camel, CXF and ActiveMQ has main components.